# Dynamic web-page or active web-page

Tags: html, dynamic

A live match score update website which refreshes automatically after every 10 seconds to fetch latest score is an example of dynamic web-page or active web-page  ?

I know that Active web-pages are downloaded in client environment and then run,
whereas Dynamic web-pages are run on the server and then the result is sent to the user.

I can't consider the above example as dynamic since the page is not loading again and again .

So should I consider it as an example of active?

Comment: Down voters please explain reason ?

Answer (score 0):

As if a website refreshed at every 10 second so it means it is on server side environment and not on client side environment so it is  dynamic web page.

Comment: But the script to fetch data from server is run on client only. Most probably ajax is used. So I think it is a combination of client side and server side, i.e. a combination of active and dynamic.